# Setting up Opengl for Borlandc++

Tags: opengl, borland-c++

I have copied the glut.h file in `c:/turbo/tc/include/` directory and *glut32.dll* in `c:/windows/System32/`.

After this what should I do ?

Comment: Did you search on google ?

Comment: Tried and got this link http://www.gantless.com/borland.html. In which I got stuck at implib command.Any idea?

Comment: Are you constrained to use Borland C++ compiler? Can't you try other free compilers like GCC (MinGW) or VC++ (VS Express Edition)?

Comment: please specify your C++ environment Compiler,OS ??? what OpenGL you want to use? old style GL 1.0 (extensions?) or newer (compatibility or core profile)? GLSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your path implies old Borland Turbo C++ 3.1 to me

- which was the old MS-DOS C++ IDE (similar to Borland TP 7.0 pascal IDE)
- in which you can not have classic 32bit OpenGL
- there were some 16bit MS-DOS versions of GL+GLUT compatible ports of glut+gl libs.
- so unless you do not have them then it will not work no matter you do
- if you do then read the provided readme.txt or whatever to see how to use it
- there were some tutorials on them but I strongly doubt you will find them on the internet
- because most of old programing portals is off-line and stuff lost forever ...

if you have newer compiler like Borland C++ BCC 5.0 or newer

- then just include headers
- link lib files for used dll's for example:

  ```
  #include "my_GL_headers\\glut.h"
  #pragma link "my_GL_headers\\glut.lib"
  ```
- use implib tool if you do not have them or are incompatible
- because most provided libs are for MSVC++
- which are incompatible with standard Intel object format
- for more info see difference between COMF and OMF
- some header files already link their lib files so do this only if you have unresolved externals ...

If you use IDE like Borland C++ builder 1,2,3,4,5,6 or Developer Studio 2006 Turbo C++

- then look at this answer of mine: [How to render an openGL frame in C++ builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679773/2521214)
- all the headers and libs are included in IDE ...

PS this is how mine usual GL includes look like in BDS2006 projects

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <jpeg.hpp>
#include <math.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "gl\glew.c"
#include "gl\gl.h"
#include "gl\glu.h"
#include "gl\glext.h"
#include "gl\wglext.h"   
#include "gl\glut.h"
```

- where gl is project source local folder
- including all headers/objs/libs ...
- the only lib you need is glut.lib (if you want to use glut)
- GLEW can be either as lib/dll/obj or as C++ source code
- I prefer the C++ source version under borland/embarcadero

Comment: I shifted to visual studio express and it works perfectly fine.