# Animation of multiply blending of two images

Tags: ios, opengl, image-processing, textures, blending

I have two images:
bg Image1 And overlay Image2 (which height is bigger than bg image1)
[image]
[image]

Now I need to place [Image2] over [Image1] with blend mode multiply.
But after that I need to animate Image2's Y position but keep blend mode so to get an animation like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4Gqm9_Eo68

So how can I achieve that?
May be I should use OpenGL? If yes, then how exactly?

Comment: the video is blank ... what effect you want to achieve ? colored scanline highlight going up/down inside image1 or the background (out of range of image2) will be black ?  anyway yes you can do this in OpenGL relatively easily ... but if you got pixel access that this is done with simple 2 nested for loops rendering although on ios devices that could be slow depending on the HW architecture...

Comment: @Spektre I've updated the video url. Please check that.

Comment: how did u make video? you have already made what you wanted... :D :P

Comment: @FahimParkar The video was made by designer :D

Comment: oldstyle OpenGL or GLSL? render quad with 2 textures combined by blending. one texture is fixed (left image) and covers whole quad and the second is blended with repeat coordinates set. x axis covers whole quad and y-axis covers just a part of right texture covering full renderd quad. The animation is done simply by changing the offset of the second  texture y-TexCoord ...  So you need MultiTexture and Blending ... no need for alpha channel as this is color masked

Comment: @Spektre yes, but I don't know OpelGL at all. Can you bring an example of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not code for **IOS** and have no clue of platform you are coding for (memory,speed,gfx capabilities). From your Question I got the impression you have no clue of rendering and also the animating part...

1. **the easiest way would be encode it yourself**

   If you got **pixel access** then it is just a matter of 2 nested for loops copying/combining pixels of texture to target color. I usually use **GDI** and `Bitmap->ScanLine[]` for this but as mentioned I have no clue if you have something similar on IOS.
2. **OpenGL**

   as you have no **OpenGL** experience then I do not advice to use **GLSL** as it could be too much from start. Things like setting up **OpenGL** environment and explaining how **OpenGL** program works would be too long even for me (and I am used to lengthy answers). So I would skip that (you need to google some tutorial for it) anyway see:

   - [Setting up OpenGL in Borland C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177014/2521214)
   - [simple rendering in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679773/2521214)

   As this require MultiTexturing you will also need that extension (At least I think those are not in **OpenGL 1.0** natively). I advice to use lib for it like **GLEW** or whatever else.

   The idea is to render quad (rectangle) with 2 textures at once something like this:

   [image: effect]

   The Quad Vertex coordinates are fixed (dependend on screen and image resolution/aspect ratio). Texture0 is also fixed And Texture1 has fixed one axis and the second is changing... where:

   - `t` is the animation parameter `t=<0,1>`
   - `T` is used gradient chunk size `T<1.0`

   The animation is done by changing `t` by some small step each frame for example increment and wrap around or use sinus...

   You need to remember that standard OpenGL knows only power of 2 textures so you need to resize/crop/resample your textures to match this criteria. I do this like this:

   [image]
   [image]

   Also you need to handle **aspect ratio** difference between your App **OpenGL** screen and image ... I used a short cut so the **OpenGL** view is square and the image is resized to square too.

   Now when using **MultiTexturing** you need to properly set up the Texture combiners to match your needs. It has been ages I used that so I do not remember it at all and too lazy to study that again as I use GLSL now ...

   - anyway see [Texture Combiners](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Combiners) if you need some guidience

   Luckily it looks like that default **OpenGL** settings of this do just what you want. So here some **C++/VCL** based code (without the **OpenGL** environment setup which is platform dependent):

   ```
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   const int _txrs=2;              // max number of textures
   GLuint  txrid[_txrs],txrids=0;  // texture ids
   GLfloat t=0.0,T=0.1,dt=0.1;     // animation texture coordinates

   void init()
       {
       glGenTextures(_txrs,txrid);

       // textures
       Byte q;
       unsigned int *pp;
       int xs,ys,x,y,adr,*txr;
       union { unsigned int c32; Byte db[4]; } c;
       Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;   // new bmp

       // image texture
       bmp->LoadFromFile("effect_image.bmp");  // load from file
       bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;      // allow direct access to pixels
       bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;   // set pixel to 32bit so int is the same size as pixel
       xs=bmp->Width;              // resolution should be power of 2
       ys=bmp->Height;
       txr=new int[xs*ys];         // create linear framebuffer
       for(adr=0,y=0;y<ys;y++)
           {
           pp=(unsigned int*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
           for(x=0;x<xs;x++,adr++)
               {
               // rgb2bgr and copy bmp -> txr[]
               c.c32=pp[x];
               q      =c.db[2];
               c.db[2]=c.db[0];
               c.db[0]=q;
               txr[adr]=c.c32;
               }
           }
       glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    // copy it to gfx card
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrid[txrids]); txrids++;
       glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
       glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, xs, ys, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txr);
       glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
       delete[] txr;

       // gradient texture
       bmp->LoadFromFile("effect_mask.bmp");   // load from file
       bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;      // allow direct access to pixels
       bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;   // set pixel to 32bit so int is the same size as pixel
       xs=bmp->Width;              // resolution should be power of 2
       ys=bmp->Height;
       txr=new int[xs*ys];         // create linear framebuffer
       for(adr=0,y=0;y<ys;y++)
           {
           pp=(unsigned int*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
           for(x=0;x<xs;x++,adr++)
               {
               // rgb2bgr and copy bmp -> txr[]
               c.c32=pp[x];
               q      =c.db[2];
               c.db[2]=c.db[0];
               c.db[0]=q;
               txr[adr]=c.c32;
               }
           }
       glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    // copy it to gfx card
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrid[txrids]); txrids++;
       glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
       glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, xs, ys, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txr);
       glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
       delete[] txr;
       T=0.4;                      // 40% of gradient height cover the whole image
       dt=0.015*T;                 // animation step 1.5% of image

       delete bmp;
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void TForm1::ogl_draw()
       {
       // clear buffers
       glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

       // unit matrices ... no projections ... so view is just <-1,+1>
       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
       glLoadIdentity();
       glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
       glLoadIdentity();
       glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
       glLoadIdentity();

       glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // no Z-buffer for 2D
       glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);    // no strict polygon winding
       glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
       // bind textures
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrid[1]);
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrid[0]);
       glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0);
       // render QUAD
       glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
       GLfloat t0=t,t1=t+T;

       glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0,0.0,0.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1,0.0,t0);
       glVertex3f(-1.0,+1.0,0.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0,0.0,1.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1,0.0,t1);
       glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0,1.0,1.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1,1.0,t1);
       glVertex2f(+1.0,-1.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0,1.0,0.0);
       glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1,1.0,t0);
       glVertex2f(+1.0,+1.0);
       glEnd();

       // unbind textures so it does not mess any rendering after this (texture unit 0 at the end !!!)
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);

       // force to render qued OpenGL rendering and swap double buffers
       glFlush();
       SwapBuffers(hdc);   // this is platform dependend !!!
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
       {
       ogl_draw();
       t+=dt;  // step the animation
       if ((dt>0.0)&&(t+T>1.0)) { t=1.0-T; dt=-dt; } // handle if hit top
       if ((dt<0.0)&&(t  <0.0)) { t=0.0; dt=-dt; }  // handle if hit bottom
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   As you can see it is quite a bit of code. If you use some lib to load textures and handle stuff most of it will go away (I use mine engine for this so it took mi while to get the pieces together again so it is usable standalone without lib). Do not forget to init **GLEW** or whatever to get access to **MultiTexturing** ...

This is simple VCL single form app with single timer in it (`interval=20ms`).

- `init()` just allocates space for textures in gfx card and load the images to it.
- `ogl_draw()` renders the effect of yours ...
- `Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)` is called on each timer event and just force to render frame and update animation ... it goes up through the gradient and then down ...

  This is the result:

  [image: result]

  Of coarse it is animated but I am to lazy to catch a video of this...

**[edit1]**

Here link to download the whole BDS2006 project [download](http://ulozto.cz/xWY5xLNM/effect-scanline-highlight-zip)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Can you send me your project's archive please? (mkrtarturdev@gmail.com)

Comment: @added edit1 with link ... also delete the comments so you do not get bots exploiting your email address

Comment: One more question. Can you tell me, what part of your code exactly do the blending job? :)

Comment: @arturdev that between `glBegin` and `glEnd` "draws" `QUAD` (4 vertex polygon) so I pass the coordinates of polygon vertexes and to whivh point in which texture it coresponds (is mapped to). the rest just configures the OpenGL to render filled polygons with 2 textures blended together ... you do not mix the colros directly in opengl the combiners do that for you ... (but still can be done with GLSL but that is too much to start with for a rookie)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
- drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:
```

Comment: Expand on the answer with details on explanation so that the OP knows what you are saying and in what context.

Comment: But how to animate that? How can I change Y position of gradient overlay image, and force to redraw while animating?