# Loading an image with Dev C++

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, dev-c++

My goal is relatively simple which is loading an image with the usage of C++. I compile and run these codes using Dev C++. I already linked these respective headers in the compiler options and in the parameter.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>


typedef union PixelInfo
{
    std::uint32_t Colour;
    struct
    {
        std::uint8_t R, G, B, A;
    };
} *PPixelInfo;

class Tga
{
private:
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;
    bool ImageCompressed;
    std::uint32_t width, height, size, BitsPerPixel;

public:
    Tga(const char* FilePath);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> GetPixels() {return this->Pixels;}
    std::uint32_t GetWidth() const {return this->width;}
    std::uint32_t GetHeight() const {return this->height;}
    bool HasAlphaChannel() {return BitsPerPixel == 32;}
};

Tga::Tga(const char* FilePath)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()){throw std::invalid_argument("File Not Found.");}

    std::uint8_t Header[18] = {0};
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> ImageData;
    static std::uint8_t DeCompressed[12] = {0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
    static std::uint8_t IsCompressed[12] = {0x0, 0x0, 0xA, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};

    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Header), sizeof(Header));

    if (!std::memcmp(DeCompressed, &Header, sizeof(DeCompressed)))
    {
        BitsPerPixel = Header[16];
        width  = Header[13] * 256 + Header[12];
        height = Header[15] * 256 + Header[14];
        size  = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

        if ((BitsPerPixel != 24) && (BitsPerPixel != 32))
        {
            hFile.close();
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid File Format. Required: 24 or 32 Bit Image.");
        }

        ImageData.resize(size);
        ImageCompressed = false;
        hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ImageData.data()), size);
    }
    else if (!std::memcmp(IsCompressed, &Header, sizeof(IsCompressed)))
    {
        BitsPerPixel = Header[16];
        width  = Header[13] * 256 + Header[12];
        height = Header[15] * 256 + Header[14];
        size  = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

        if ((BitsPerPixel != 24) && (BitsPerPixel != 32))
        {
            hFile.close();
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid File Format. Required: 24 or 32 Bit Image.");
        }

        PixelInfo Pixel = {0};
        int CurrentByte = 0;
        std::size_t CurrentPixel = 0;
        ImageCompressed = true;
        std::uint8_t ChunkHeader = {0};
        int BytesPerPixel = (BitsPerPixel / 8);
        ImageData.resize(width * height * sizeof(PixelInfo));

        do
        {
            hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ChunkHeader), sizeof(ChunkHeader));

            if(ChunkHeader < 128)
            {
                ++ChunkHeader;
                for(int I = 0; I < ChunkHeader; ++I, ++CurrentPixel)
                {
                    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Pixel), BytesPerPixel);

                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.B;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.G;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.R;
                    if (BitsPerPixel > 24) ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.A;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ChunkHeader -= 127;
                hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Pixel), BytesPerPixel);

                for(int I = 0; I < ChunkHeader; ++I, ++CurrentPixel)
                {
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.B;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.G;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.R;
                    if (BitsPerPixel > 24) ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.A;
                }
            }
        } while(CurrentPixel < (width * height));
    }
    else
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid File Format. Required: 24 or 32 Bit TGA File.");
    }

    hFile.close();
    this->Pixels = ImageData;
}


int main()
{
    Tga info = Tga("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/OpenGL/sabahpride.tga");

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, info.GetWidth(), info.GetWidth(), 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, info.GetPixels().data());

}
```

The code is successfully compiled but when I run the .exe file, it does not show anything; seems like does not process anything at all. I've been working on loading this image for a few days already but to no avail. I would really appreciate it if there are other solutions.
When I ran the debugger it shows an error which says `[Error] can't create precompiled header Flag of Sabah.exe: Permission denied`

I also tried using openCV to load the image and it can compile but would not run at all and does not create any .exe file

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 // Read the image file
 Mat image = imread("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/New folder/sabahpride.jpg");

 // Check for failure
 if (image.empty()) 
 {
  cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
  cin.get(); //wait for any key press
  return -1;
 }

 String windowName = "The Flag"; //Name of the window

 namedWindow(windowName); // Create a window

 imshow(windowName, image); // Show our image inside the created window.

 waitKey(0); // Wait for any keystroke in the window

 destroyWindow(windowName); //destroy the created window

 return 0;
}
```

The task is due tomorrow so I really need the help that I can. Thank you.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your program, when it allegedly loads and displays an image, what did your debugger show was happening? Was it reading the file?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thank you for replying, I forgot to input that when I used the debugger, it shows [Error] can't create precompiled header Flag of Sabah.exe: Permission denied

Comment: Debuggers have nothing to do with creating precompiled headers. They don't compile anything. You should invest some time in learning how to debug your own code. Knowing how to use a debuggers is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: 1. you did not initialized OpenGL 2. You are not rendering anything I see no old `glBegin/glEnd` nor new `glDraw` 3. I see no `glClear` nor swapping of buffers ... see [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) for the new style and [How to render an openGL frame in C++ builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679773/2521214) for the old one. Try to copy your TGA where your EXE is and get rid of the paths ... you most likely have wrong path syntax `folder/folder/...` some environments/functions need `folder\\folder\\...`  are you sure file opens?